# GWT uploading a photo

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, uibinder

I m using Google App Engine (1.7) to store my entities on Datastore and GWT 2.4 to build the interface. Some entities have an image field, so a user when submits a new Entity (a "Product" for example) can upload her one image (of the product).

So my question is how I can create an upload field where the browsing window will appear when the user clicks in an element and after the upload process a thumbnail of that image will appear in this element!!

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Check out GWT FileUpload component.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial. I think it does exactly what you need:
[GWT, Blobstore, the new high performance image serving API](http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/)

Answer (score 0):

"GWT Upload" is the best choice i have found. I have used it outside GAE (in my own application server) but i think it has GAE support as well. Basically to make it work you need to put the "GWT Upload control" onto your page, write the server side uploader (extending one provided) add some lines to web.xml, and that's it.